# Transactional producer in rdkafka

Tags: c, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I am trying to create transactional producer in c using librdkafka library.Below is the code how i created the transactional producer using librdkafka library

**how i created:-**

```
    char *brokers = "localhost:9092"; // Kafka broker(s) address

    char *topic = "mytopic";          // Kafka topic name

    rd_kafka_t *rk; //producer handle

    rd_kafka_conf_t *conf; //conf handle
    char errstr[512];

  
    conf = rd_kafka_conf_new(); 
    if (rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "bootstrap.servers", brokers, errstr, sizeof(errstr)) != RD_KAFKA_CONF_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%% Configuration failed: %s\n", errstr);
        return 1;
    }

    if (rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "transactional.id", "100", errstr, sizeof(errstr)) != RD_KAFKA_CONF_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%% Configuration failed for producer in bootstrapping: %s\n", errstr);
    }

    rk = rd_kafka_new(RD_KAFKA_PRODUCER, conf, errstr, sizeof(errstr));
    if (!rk)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%% Failed to create producer: %s\n", errstr);
        return 1;
    }
```

My Question :- Is there any way to reuse already created producer instance to send another transaction like 101..?